# Grails MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException thrown

Tags: mysql, spring, grails

I created a Grails application and deployed it to a Tomcat server. I have configured the Grails application to use an external MySQL database. After I start the Tomcat server and the application deploys (and the database schema is created), I run a script that will transfer relational data from multiple tables in an existing database to the new database that was generated by the Grails application.

The script runs without problems, and **there are no database errors during the INSERTs.**

After the insert, I use my Grails application an see all of the existing data with no problems.

There is a problem, however, if I stop the Tomcat server and then start it up again.  I am faced with the following error in catalina.out:

```
2013-01-15 00:43:37,820 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
2013-01-15 00:43:37,826 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2024)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1976)
        ... 9 more
```

I am confused by this error because if duplicate data exists, how could the information have successfully been inserted in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the batch data migration script executed again?

Answer (score 0):

Check your BootStrap.groovy file and check that you don`t insert nothing in the database that exists

Example:
def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") ?: new Role(authority: "ROLE_ADMIN").save(failOnError: true)